# connect tcp winsocket to c# dot net server

Tags: c#, sockets, winapi, tcp

here is the problem. I want to connect a **win32 api app** to a c# dot net app through a **tcp socket** connection. The **C#** server is looking like that:

```
public class MyServer
{

    // Incoming data from the client.
    public static string data = null;

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the 
        // host running the application.
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and 
        // listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(10);

            // Start listening for connections.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
                Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                data = null;

                // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    if (data.IndexOf("\n") > -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);
                        data=null;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        StartListening();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

which is very simple, not perfect but it's proved to do its job. The **Win32 API** program is the following:

```
DWORD WINAPI myThread(LPVOID lpParameter) {

    int iResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    //addrinfo holds host address information
    SOCKADDR_IN clientService;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";


    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    clientService.sin_port = htons(11000);

    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & clientService, sizeof (clientService));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // Should really try the next address returned by getaddrinfo
    // if the connect call failed
    // But for this simple example we just free the resources
    // returned by getaddrinfo and print an error message


    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int) strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection for sending since no more data will be sent
    // the client can still use the ConnectSocket for receiving data
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

}
```

The simplified main is:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    DWORD myThreadID;

    //thread creation
    myHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, myThread, &myCounter, 0, &myThreadID);

    while(1 > 0)
    {
        //do some stuffs
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So basically I'm trying to connect to the local host on port **11000**. First start the server, then when I debug the **win32 api** program I got a **SOCKET_ERROR**, after calling the `connect` function.

Is it possible that the inet_addr return the wrong IP address version (6 instead of 4)?

Thanks.

P.S. The problem is definitely not in the network, since this is a loop-back connection to the localhost, and as mentioned the server is tested to be working with another client (written in c#) on the same machine, address and port.

Another interesting fact that I notice during debugging is that the `clientService.sin_addr.s_addr` is `16777343`, but the value of `ipAddress.Address` is `2399212554`.

**Update**: I've just tested the winapi client with the provided [winsock server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx) and it worked out very well. That means that the problem is an incompatibility between the c# server and the winapi client. So the question is what is not compatible? IP addresses, sockets configurations or something else?

Comment: I suggest you download a tcp/ip client server app - many exist and see if any of them able to make a connection to itself regardless of your code so you can be sure the problem is with the code and not with your current network configuration.. ie router, network card, hardware, firewall..

Comment: The problem is not in the network. I have a client written in c# perfectly working with the server. The problem is in the code of the winapi client or it is some incompatibility between the two programs, which I honestly doubt, certainly it is exactly somewhere in the code posted.

Comment: is server being reached at all - if you put breakpoint in its code on that line: `Socket handler = listener.Accept();` do you get to it?

Comment: The program is not continuing after that line. It's expected since the client can't connect to the server. What's your point?

Comment: but is it being reached in server side ? my point is to try to rule out some of the problems which might cause it - if server side get to the line so the break point will reach we can know for sure it is not an IP or Port issue and continue from there.

Comment: Of course it is reached. I've already stated that the server is being tested with a c# client and it's working. The problem is for sure in the IP address it is not in the port. And it is not in the algorithm of the client as you can see from the update.

Comment: Its not IP address problem - try to send small length data like ABC and try to wait few seconds between connect and send. any results?

Comment: I can't send anything, even one byte. The connect is blowing, I can't even get to send.

Comment: How is it possible the connect is blowing on client side and is reaching to `Accept()` on server side?! What you describing is wrong somehow, could it be a problem on Accept in server side that fails your client?

Comment: It's reaching the accept on server side, but stayed there and went no further. This should be the expected behavior of the server, when there is no client, or there is a client wrongly connecting.

Comment: Can you try the whole thing on a different machine and see if same result?